# How to play animations in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, animation, cocos2d-x

I'm new to Cocos2d-x and looking for a good way/tutorial on how to play animations in Cocos2d-x.

Comment: Checkout this https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRtjMdoYXLf4od_bOKN3WjAPr7snPXzoe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sprite animation is pretty simple. You just create a `CCAnimation` node, add the images to loop, then create an action using `CCAnimate::actionWithDuration(float, CCAnimation, bool)` and make the sprite run it.

**Example:**

```
CCAnimation * anim = CCAnimation::animation();
// There are other several ways of storing + adding frames, 
// this is the most basic using one image per frame.
anim->addFrameWithFileName("bear1.png");
anim->addFrameWithFileName("bear2.png");
anim->addFrameWithFileName("bear3.png");
anim->addFrameWithFileName("bear4.png");
anim->addFrameWithFileName("bear5.png");
anim->addFrameWithFileName("bear6.png");
anim->addFrameWithFileName("bear7.png");
anim->addFrameWithFileName("bear8.png");

CCAnimate *theAnim = CCAnimate::actionWithDuration(1.8f,anim,true); 
// Duration, animation action and bool to return to frame 1 after finishing.

CCSprite *bear = CCSprite::spriteWithFile("bear1.png");
addChild(bear,0); //Don't forget to add any sprite you use as a child to the CCLayer!
bear->runAction(theAnim);
```

Comment: Thanks but what is HelloWorld::getPlayer() ? I'm getting a crash on iPhone simulator on adding runAction(laanim); to my code.

Comment: You can use a sprite or any other node you want, I have a method that returns a static sprite called _player that I have previously initialized.

Comment: I edited it for clarity now :) You are welcome.

Comment: `CCAnimate *theAnim = CCAnimate::actionWithDuration(1.8f,anim,true); ` doesn't work with the current version of cocos2d-x. What has to be changed?

Comment: Probably, they revamped a lot of stuff lately. Dunno what now, just check their documentation and maybe you need one parameter more/less.

Comment: For the Cocos2D V3 version of above, see the documentation here: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Sprite_Sheet_Animation

Answer (score 5):

In new version of CoCos2dx (2.1.1) you can use (it's working)

```
CCSpriteFrameCache* cache = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();
cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("numbers.plist","numbers.png");

CCSprite* sprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName("slice2_0_0.png"));
sprite->setPosition(ccp(GameScene::windowSize.width/2,GameScene::windowSize.height/3));

CCSpriteBatchNode* spriteBatchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("numbers.png");
spriteBatchNode->addChild(sprite);
addChild(spriteBatchNode);

CCArray* animFrames = CCArray::createWithCapacity(10);

char str[100] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    sprintf(str, "slice2_0_%d.png", i);
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = cache->spriteFrameByName( str );
    animFrames->addObject(frame);
}
CCAnimation* animation = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames,1.f);
sprite->runAction(CCAnimate::create(animation) );
```

Comment: There's an edit to this question in the edit review queue which renames `spriteWithSpriteFrame` to `createWithSpriteFrame`. I don't know enough Cocos2D to tell if it is an improvement. Would the edit improve this answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a *.plist* file and want to continue with the [Ef Es](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/14349/ef-es)'s answer with the current version of cocos2d-x, just change some lines as below:

```
    CCSprite * sprite  = CCSprite::create("bear1.png"); // NEW - create a sprite here
    CCAnimation * anim = CCAnimation::animation();
    // There are other several ways of storing + adding frames, 
    // this is the most basic using one image per frame.
    anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("bear1.png");
    anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("bear2.png");
    anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("bear3.png");
    anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("bear4.png");
    anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("bear5.png");
    anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("bear6.png");
    anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("bear7.png");
    anim->addSpriteFrameWithFileName("bear8.png");

    anim->setLoops(-1); // for infinit loop animation
    anim->setDelayPerUnit(0.1f); //Duration per frame
    //CCAnimate *theAnim = CCAnimate::actionWithDuration(1.8f,anim,true); // this wont work in newer version..

    sprite->runAction(CCAnimate::create(anim) );
    sprite->setPosition(ccp(200,200)); //set position of sprite in some visible area

    this->addChild(sprite, 1); // cross check the Z index = 1 with your code
```

I think this can be the solution for [Ben](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/9322/ben)'s question also.

Answer (score 0):

For cocos2dx-v3, you'll need something like this:

```
auto cache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
Vector<SpriteFrame*> frames = Vector<SpriteFrame*>();

frames.pushBack(cache->getSpriteFrameByName("open.png"));
frames.pushBack(cache->getSpriteFrameByName("closed.png"));
frames.pushBack(cache->getSpriteFrameByName("closed.png"));
cocos2d::Animation* anim = cocos2d::Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(frames, 0.1f, 1);

cocos2d::Animate* anim_action = cocos2d::Animate::create(anim);
//sprite is already added to scene elsewhere and ready to go
this->sprite->runAction(RepeatForever::create(anim_action));
```

Wasn't able to get any other way going. You're also able to re-add the same frames over and over again to introduce a pause, but I'm sure there's another way of doing that too.

Comment: Can you tell me how you would run the same animation, but with the sprites flipped horizontally ? I've been struggling with this for a while now, and setFlippedX(true) doesn't seem to do it...